# Custom taxonomy and post type with same slug

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I'm using the plugin "types" to register the custom taxonomy and post types,

and got 404 when using the same slug for them to display them hierarchy, like this:

```
 site.com/tax    //taxonomy archive
 site.com/tax/post-type    //entry
```

how to make this url structure work ?  (notice i'm using a plugin to register tax, types and rewrite)

Thanks